# Затруднение с реализация алгоритма рандомизации значения точек

Tags: c++, c

У меня вопрос следующего порядка. Есть программа в одном .cpp, с главной функцией, остальными функциями. Есть очень важный, предопределяемый вне тела каждой из функций, "параметр", а именно, массив координат пяти точек. Нужно сделать так, чтоб их значения менялись в зависимости от rand коэффициента (от тех значений, которые приведены в коде). Я пытался и через объявление srand time null в int main + непосредственно после инклюдов рассчитать этот коэфф в определенном целочисленном диапазоне, однако он никоим образом (что очевидно), не изменялся. Инициализацию массива точек в тело главной функции green_poly_points кидал - однако тогда вся программа ничего не видит (необъявленные идентификаторы). Как мне решить данную проблему?

```
 //

    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>

    using namespace std;  

     int koeff = 1 + rand() % 4 ; 

double xx1 = koeff*45-35; 
double xx2 = koeff*50-35; 
double xx3 = koeff*30-25; 
double xx4 = koeff*15-10; 
double xx5 = koeff*10-5; 
double yy1 = koeff*45-15; 
double yy2 = koeff*28-18; 
double yy3 = koeff*35-10; 
double yy4 = koeff*25-10; 
double yy5 = koeff*50-25; 

int green_poly_points [20][2] = {{xx1,yy1}, {xx2,yy2}, 

{xx3,yy3}, {xx4,yy4}, 
{xx5,yy5}};



    --///функции разнообразной обработки значений точек

    int main(int argc,char *argv[])

    {


    srand(time(0));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, в Си *(вопрос помечен меткой* ***c*** *)* 
эта программа компилироваться не будет.
Предполагаю, что вы используете С++ компилятор.

В таком случае, все действия по инициализации переменных вне функций выполняется **перед вызовом main()**.

Поэтому вызов `srand()` внутри `main()` не влияет на число, возвращаемое `rand()` при инициализации `koeff`.

Перенесите всю вашу инициализацию в функцию, (например, `init_data()`), которую вызывайте из `main()` *после* вызова `srand()`.

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;  

int koeff;
double xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4, xx5,
  yy1, yy2, yy3, yy4, yy5;

int green_poly_points [20][2];


void init_data ()
{

  koeff = 1 + rand() % 4 ; 

  xx1 = koeff*45-35; 
  xx2 = koeff*50-35; 
  xx3 = koeff*30-25; 
  xx4 = koeff*15-10; 
  xx5 = koeff*10-5; 
  yy1 = koeff*45-15; 
  yy2 = koeff*28-18; 
  yy3 = koeff*35-10; 
  yy4 = koeff*25-10; 
  yy5 = koeff*50-25;

  green_poly_points[0][0] = xx1;   green_poly_points[0][1] = yy1; 
  green_poly_points[1][0] = xx2;   green_poly_points[1][1] = yy2; 
  green_poly_points[2][0] = xx3;   green_poly_points[2][1] = yy3; 
  green_poly_points[3][0] = xx1;   green_poly_points[3][1] = yy4;
  green_poly_points[4][0] = xx5;   green_poly_points[4][1] = yy5;


}

///функции разнообразной обработки значений точек


int
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{


  srand(time(0));
  init_data();


  cout << green_poly_points[0][0] << "  "
       <<    green_poly_points[0][1] << "  "
       << green_poly_points[1][0] << "  "
       <<    green_poly_points[1][1]
       << '\n';
}
```

Проще сразу показать работающий вариант.

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ txx.cpp
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
55  75  65  38
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
10  30  15  10
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

С примером компиляции и двумя запусками, демонстрирующими работу `srand()`

Comment: `int init_ext_vars(int koeff)
{

int xx1 = koeff*45-35; 
int xx2 = koeff*50-35; 
int xx3 = koeff*30-25; 
int xx4 = koeff*15-10; 
int xx5 = koeff*10-5; 
int yy1 = koeff*45-15; 
int yy2 = koeff*28-18; 
int yy3 = koeff*35-10; 
int yy4 = koeff*25-10; 
int yy5 = koeff*50-25; 
 
green_poly_points [20][2] = {{xx1,yy1}, {xx2,yy2}, 
 
{xx3,yy3}, {xx4,yy4}, 
{xx5,yy5}};

}`

Comment: int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   
    srand(time(0));
 int koefff = 1 + rand() % 4 ; 
    init_ext_vars(koefff);

Comment: error C2065: green_poly_points: необъявленный идентификатор - по-прежнему

Comment: Не знаю, почему у вас необъявленный идентификатор, наверное где-то опечатки. Привел пример кода для такой программы, только хотел бы сразу предупредить, использование глобальных переменных не слишком хорошая идея (разные обоснования этого можете поискать самостоятельно в инете)

Comment: Спасибо, а какая правильная альтернативная глобальному определению в такого род задачах?

Comment: Если совокупность данных используется совместно в разных функциях, то я бы объединил их в структуру, выделил для нее память (в С++ через new) в фукции `init_data()` и вернул указатель на эту структуру, который передавал бы во все фукции, где эти данные используются